# How to use API call in service in Iconic2

Tags: api, ionic-framework, service, ionic2

I am calling following function on click of button.

login.ts

```
public login() {
this.showLoading()

this.http.get('http://laravel.dev/test').map(res => res).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data)
},
  error => {
    this.showError(error);
  });
}
```

What I want that this API call should be come from service file. As I am new to Ionic 2 That's Why I am unable to get how can I call above API through service and receive it in `login.ts`.

`auth.service.ts`

```
public login(credentials) {
        // Here I want to call Above API and return it to the `login.ts`
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `http.get` request is an Observable. You can return the observable from the service and subscribe in the component/page.

**auth.service.ts**

```
public login(credentials) {
   return this.http.get('http://laravel.dev/test').map(res => res.json())
}
```

`map` function returns the data after decoding the `json` response assuming your http returns json.

**login.ts**

```
public login() {
this.showLoading()

this.authService.login(credentials).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data)
},
  error => {
    this.showError(error);
  },
  ()=>this.dismissLoading());
}
```

Inject the service through the constructor in your component and subscribe to the login function.

Comment: Worked.Thanks@ suraj

Comment: I would like to ask one more thing that, How can I send the credentials which I received in service method's argument with Api `this.http.get('http://laravel.dev/test').map(res => res.json())` so that I can receive it in backend. @suraj

Comment: depends on how you are receiving it.. I suggest you use `this.http.post` to send in the body

Comment: If I am passing like this then it works, `return this.http.post('http://laravel.dev/test',credentials).map(res => res)`  But If I want to pass like `return this.http.post('http://laravel.dev/test','data' : credentials).map(res => res)` then I am not getting How can I do that?